# But how to align the equality sign $=$ balanced?

Tags: vertical-alignment, brackets

See the following latex keywords

```
\[\left\{\begin{matrix}
A=B \\ C=D
\end{matrix}\right.\]
```

This shows the two array as column wise in center part.

But how to align the equality sign $=$ balanced?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). In the example you give it seems that the two equal signs _are_ aligned, so not sure what the actual problem is. Also, while code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT:** As suggested by @egreg :-) I add another answer using ambient `cases`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{cases}
A =& B \\
C =& D
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

As correctly pointed out by the good user who gave you the first correct answer, if you do not indicate the precise packages that you have used we can not help you very well. In fact, to get it, I used another code that produces the same result using the ambient `aligned`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
A &= B \\
C &= D
\end{aligned}
\right.
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would use `cases` anyhow, instead of `\left\{` and `\right.` The answer is good otherwise.

Comment: +1 for showing how to align the contents of the two rows on the `=` symbols.

Comment: @egreg Correct and precise observation. Thank you also to Mico :-) Thank you very very much for your collaboration and for everything you're teaching me. English a little bit better than two years ago but we are still a long way from a precise and correct English :-).-)

Comment: @Sebastiano, thanks for your nice answer. If I request you further, I know that 'belong to' can be written in latex as $ \in $ this gives  $x \in A$, but I need to write the set at first and then the element , something like $A  \ contain  \ x$. How to write this?

Comment: I don't think egreg meant for you to get rid of the `aligned` environment. Instead, I'm pretty sure he meant for you to keep using an `aligned` environment, while replacing the `\left\{\begin{matrix}` and `\end{matrix}\right.` directives with `\begin{cases}` and `\end{cases}`, respectively.

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR It is good practice to post a different question for a new problem. And we would love to get a **full** working code this time.  But, for the time being, does [this link](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Symbols:Set_Operations_and_Relations#Contains_as_an_Element) help?

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR Meanwhile, I'm flattered by your compliments :-). I answer you as sincerely as I did under other circumstances. I personally am here on this site to learn from colleagues who are good and less good with this program. I add, here, once again that I am here enrolled to better help others. I am not interested in scoring and medals at all. I have read your new question. Good practice on TeX.SE. as correctly described by Partha D. is to ask another question since what you ask me is different from your main question. Greetings.

Comment: @Sebastiano, ok I apologies for making another question

Comment: @ParthaD., thanks. I apologies for  asking another different question

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR Don't worry. We are here for help you. No apologies :-). You are here "welcome".

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR It's perfectly all right... there's noone who comes into this world knowing everything. Hope you will (and already are) enjoy(ing) the ambience of the community. Feel free to post your queries and contribute in the way you feel best.

Answer (score 4):

I think using the `amsmath` package should bring your matrix to shape:

[image]

with the code snippet:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
    \left\{
    \begin{matrix}
        A=B\\ 
        C=D
    \end{matrix}
    \right.
\] 
\end{document}
```

However, without loading the `amsmath` package

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
    \left\{
    \begin{matrix}
        A=B\\ 
        C=D
    \end{matrix}
    \right.
\] 
\end{document}
```

it gives:

[image]

With a warm welcome to TeX.SX, it is advised, as @Peter Grill pointed out, that you include in your future questions a full working example (as minimal as possible) with all packages you have used and the appropriate documentclass... so that contributors are able to locate your exact problem and help you (and future [La]TeX users) better.

Comment: Your screenshot appears to be missing a linebreak between `A=B` and `C=D`.

Comment: @Mico But that's what I get without any packages loaded. The linebreak appears only with `\includepackage{amsmath}`. Frankly speaking, I don't know the reason for that... maybe the `matrix` environment is defined differently there!

Comment: The missing linebreak occurs precisely because you're not loading the `amsmath` package. The LaTeX kernel actually defines an environment called `matrix`, and that's what ends up being used because you're not loading the `amsmath` package, which provides a far more competent and polished environment with the same name. For the example at hand, I can see no valid reason for not loading the `amsmath` package.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for the explanation. My answer does suggest using `amsmath` to let the linebreak take effect... producing the [first screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeOh5.png). I added the [second screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cXbS.png) in a later edit to give an idea of what happens when amsmath package is not loaded. Your valuable explanation completes the cycle by providing the logic for the observed difference.